# webkit device:0 and sticky-header conflict

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I am using this iOS fix to prevent scrolling side to side (overflow-x).

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) { 
    body, html {overflow-x: hidden;}
}
```

However, the javascript below and the -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio do not work together. If I remove the min-device, then sticky works, but there is now a scroll side-by side. When I add the min-device, the sticky breaks, but side by side scroll works as expected.

```js
$(function(){
 var shrinkHeader = 50;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = getCurrentScroll();
      if ( scroll >= shrinkHeader ) {
           $('.top-bar').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else {
            $('.top-bar').removeClass('shrink');
        }
  });
```

Is there a solution to get both of these working together?

Answer (score 0):

I simplified by script, and now it works.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('.top-bar').addClass("shrink");
  }
  else{
    $('.top-bar').removeClass("shrink");
  }
});
```